# Passing different date values for the same method

Tags: c#, oop, function, parameter-passing

I need to pass date param to a method which may be of different dates
for example the date may be expirydate or createddate?

How do i pass to a method

```
void dosomething(?datetime whateverthedate)
{
// doawesomehere
}
```

I am limited to .net 4.0 framework.

Comment: Very unclear what you are looking for - you already can pass whatever date you want to a method that takes `DateTime` as argument ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
void DoSomethingWithExpiryDate(DateTime expiryDate)
{
    ...
}

void DoSomethingWithCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate)
{
    ...
}
```

I know that seems a bit facetious, but you get the point.

But otherwise, consider wrapping the two pieces of data (date and kind) into a single class, and pass an instance of that instead:

```
enum DateItemKind
{
    ExpiryDate,
    CreatedDate
}

class DateItem
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public DateItemKind Kind { get; set; }
}

void DoSomething(DateItem dateItem)
{
    switch (dateItem.Kind)
    ...
```

**But wait, There's More!**

Whenever I see type/enum switches like that, I think "virtual method".

So perhaps the best approach would be to use an abstract base class to capture the commonality, and have a virtual method for the `DoSomething()` that anything can call without having to switch on a type/enum.

It also keeps the different logic for the different kinds of date completely separate:

```
abstract class DateItem
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public abstract virtual void DoSomething();
}

sealed class CreatedDate: DateItem
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something with CreatedDate");
    }
}

sealed class ExpiryDate: DateItem
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something with ExpiryDate");
    }
}
```

Then you can just use `DoSomething()` directly without worrying about the type:

```
void DoStuff(DateItem dateItem)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date = " + dateItem.DateTime);
    dateItem.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you want.

If you want a function that will do something to a `DateTime`, then you'd do it like this:

```
 public DateTime AddThreeDays(DateTime date)
 {
     return DateTime.AddDays(3);
 }
```

and you'd use it like:

```
 DateTime oldDate = DateTime.Today;
 DateTime newDate = AddThreeDays(oldDate);
```

If you want one that will do different things to different `DateTime`s, depending on what they represent, you should split it into different functions.

Answer (score -2):

```
    void dosomething(DateTime? dateVal, int datetype  )
    {
//datetype could be 1= expire , 2 = create  , etc 
    // doawesomehere
    }
```

Comment: Don't use magic ints for this.  At the very least use an Enum, although I'm not sure even that approach is appropriate here.

Comment: It seems like this function should be rethought, and hopefully generalized.